# Selection of text in core text like ibook

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsstring, core-text

i done a bible application which uses core text for showing verses in a view...the txt came from locally stored sqlite db,,,i am using this core text wrapper for rendering my text,,,becz it support multi column view ,,[core text warpper](https://github.com/akosma/CoreTextWrapper),,,but i need the selection of verse functionality...if the user tap the verse it need to select that particular verse,,if i have this verse 1 The God create Heave and earth . 2 etc etc,,, . 3 etc etc,,,, . when the user tap the first verse it need to select that verse and highlight that verse.....like the eBible app or ibook app...

Is there any example to show this kind of functionality in core text..Plz give me a link which might be helpful .
Thabnks in advcance.

Comment: god loves proper punctuation (and correct spelling)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar in my Bible app (https://github.com/photokandyStudios/gbible). In particular, see https://github.com/photokandyStudios/gbible/blob/master/gbible/PKBibleViewController.m#L1301

Essentially I maintain a selection array, and when a user taps the verse (in my case a uitableviewcell), I add it to the array. I also color the background of the cell to reflect the selection.

It isn't word-perfect selection with the loupe, but for my purposes, good enough.

Comment: ,,i have done the same effect in my iPhone bible app,,bu t am using core text in my iPad bible...so the selection is not done ith tableviwew,,,,

Comment: You should be able to receive touch events, then (see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW3) and then check to see which verse the point falls in to. A little painful, but probably the only way to do it, as far as I know. [This is why I used a table + core text: I could tell exactly which verse was where. Even then, though, I still had to record the position of each word inside, so almost everything in the table is being typeset by my own code.)

Comment: you r correct,,,but by using tableview we didn't get the inline text like the ibook,,thats what i wanttt...i don't know how to get the correct verse when tapping.....

Comment: What you'd need to have is an array of the location of all the words or phrases. So as you're typesetting the content (which I do see you're using a wrapper, so you'd need to adjust it a bit, maybe a lot) you would store the position of the content. This is what I do in my app (each table has to have typeset content). See https://github.com/photokandyStudios/gbible/blob/master/gbible/PKBible.m#L477 for an example of calculating content and returning an array.

Comment: The table cell which then finally displays the content is given a series of lightweight labels (PKLabels -- core text, essentially: UILabel is too expensive), and they correspond exactly to a location generated by the function pointed to above.

Now, when I receive a long-press, I first detect the cell I'm on (which you would skip), and then I iterate through all the words in that cell (for you, the page) to see which word is /nearest/ the press coordinates. (This is to handle pressing in margins or blank lines.) In your position, I'd tag the word with verse info, so you'd get that for free.

Comment: ,,,,thanks for the information,,i will try my level best...will inform you tmroo what happens ...i give you +1 for your help.