# ARC issue in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

i am checking a sample project from github an i got this error,,in one of the class,,there are many classes in  it,,but i got door in this class only.the error is "receiver type view controller for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'loadChapter:forBook'

the error came in this method,

```
- (void)displayBook: (int)theBook andChapter: (int)theChapter andVerse: (int)theVerse
{

    [((PKRootViewController *)self.parentViewController.parentViewController ) showWaitingIndicator];
    PKWait(//here i got this error
           [self loadChapter:theChapter forBook:theBook];
           //[self.tableView reloadData];
           [self reloadTableCache];
           [(PKHistory *)[PKHistory instance] addPassagewithBook:theBook andChapter:theChapter andVerse:theVerse];
           [self notifyChangedHistory];
           ((PKSettings *)[PKSettings instance]).topVerse = theVerse;
           if (theVerse>1)
           {
               [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:theVerse-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
           }
           else 
           {
               [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
           }
           UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController.parentViewController;
           tbc.selectedIndex = 0;
           );
}
```

and also this method have also this error

```
 - (void)loadChapter: (int)theChapter forBook: (int)theBook
    {
        // clear selectedVerses
        selectedVerses = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        PKSettings *theSettings = [PKSettings instance];
        theSettings.currentBook = theBook;
        theSettings.currentChapter = theChapter;
        //[theSettings saveCurrentReference]; -- removed for speed
        [self loadChapter];//here i got the error,,in this case after selector'loadChapter;
    }
```

what is the reason for this error,,in error showing window it shows,automaticReferenceCounting Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a selector loadChapter without parameters?

aslo check if their declaration is included in interface file or not

Comment: @ The Saad there is no interface declaration for this...but this is a method - (void)loadChapter: (int)theChapter forBook: (int)theBook
    {...then why need to declare in interface?

Comment: because you are acessing this method, and compiler don't know about this method as you have not declared it, you must have to predefined all things that you want to use late, like a variable, if you dont define it, it will generate an error, the same thing is here, in ARC, you will either declare it in interface or define it in implementation above it's usage, i mean above the method, in which it is accessed

Comment: tell me if you get the solution

Comment: @ The Saad so can i declare this - (void)loadChapter: (int)theChapter forBook: (int)theBook in interface?

Comment: sure u can, in fact you should, also that of -(void) loadChapter;

Comment: plz look at this question also..i hope u can help me....this is the main problem i am facing in my project.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468075/selection-of-text-in-core-text-like-ibook/10468195#10468195

Comment: in fact i've my final exam of masters tomo, n it will take some time for me to understand. sorry for late.

Answer (score 1):

The error `receiver type view controller for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'loadChapter:forBook'` means that the compiler can't found the method `loadChapter:forBook:` on the interface declaration of `self`. The same think happens on the other error, but with the method `loadChapter`. So the problem probably is that you have forgot to declare the methods on the interface, or maybe that you have declare two methods with the same name.